# Can't recover the json response from a web server

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm creating a cordova-apache application  where i communicate with a web server (get and post http request to http://192.168.1.1/cgi/json/****)

To recover the response from the server I added this code:

```
http.addEventListener("load", processRequest, false);

function processRequest()
{
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
           alert("processRequest");
           alert(http.responseText);
           var response = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

           alert("response1 =" + response);
           var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(response);
           alert("session1"+obj.id);
           var myParams =obj.parameters;
           session_ID = myParams.id;
           alert("session2"+ myParams.id);
      }


}
```

When I debug, the debugger doesn't enter to the processRequest() function and I can't recover the session id within I send the second request 'Post'

The environment I'm using:

- ubuntu
- cordova version: 6.1.1
- nodejs version :v0.10.25
- Firefox

in the network console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.25.1/cgi/json-req?req=%7B%22request%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22session-id%22%3A%220%22%2C%22priority%22%3Atrue%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22method%22%3A%22logIn%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22user%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22persistent%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22session-options%22%3A%7B%22nss%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gtw%22%2C%22uri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fsagemcom.com%2Fgateway-data%22%7D%5D%2C%22language%22%3A%22ident%22%2C%22context-flags%22%3A%7B%22get-content-name%22%3Atrue%2C%22local-time%22%3Atrue%2C%22no-default%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22capability-depth%22%3A2%2C%22capability-flags%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3Atrue%2C%22default-value%22%3Atrue%2C%22restriction%22%3Atrue%2C%22description%22%3Afalse%2C%22flags%22%3Atrue%2C%22type%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22time-format%22%3A%22ISO_8601%22%2C%22depth%22%3A2%2C%22write-only-string%22%3A%22_XMO_WRITE_ONLY_%22%2C%22undefined-write-only-string%22%3A%22_XMO_UNDEFINED_WRITE_ONLY_%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22cnonce%22%3A7462007388%2C%22auth-key%22%3A%222709a8e8d717a3a0fbcad62941c00a30%22%7D%7D. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: what is http? a XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: i have defined a variable,
var http=xmlHttpRequest;

Comment: So what do you see in the network tab in your developer console?

Comment: GET http://192.168.25.1/cgi/json-req?req=%7B%22reques...2%3A%222709a8e8d717a3a0fbcad62941c00a30%22%7D%7D
request5.js (line 117)

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.25.1/cgi/json-req?req=..

Comment: ... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: mr  epascarello when i run a native android application it works !!!
so the probleme is not ine the server !!

Comment: What language are you using in your backend?

Comment: language: javascript

Answer (score 0):

it's about config persmission , just put the the appropriate configuration